# How to set up the rule in Eagle for a type-C connector?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

[image: I Draw a package for a type C connector]

When I put it in to board editor, I get many errors. How to set up rule in Eagle?

[image]

Comment: You have pads literally touching each other. Your footprint is broken, and eagle is correctly warning you about that.

Comment: `I got many error` ... what errors?

Comment: Assuming this is USB type C why can't you just import the symbol from drawings provided by the connector vendor? (I'm genuinely curious about why this can't be done, since I'm currently investigating which PCB CAD softwares that are good at this.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "Restring" settings in the DRC settings which will be overwriting the library pad sizes in the board causing them to grow and touch each other.

In pre-Autodesk Eagle, this was under DRC settings -> Restring:
[image: DRC Settings View]

Not sure where it is in the newer versions of eagle.